# In debugging, how to set breakpoints in expressions?

Tags: debugging

In (the most widely used) programming languages there is a distinction between "statements" (function or loops bodies, assignments... basically "the stuff that ends with a ';'") and "expression" (simple calculations, function / method invocation ... "the stuff you can assign to a variable"),
so far so good.

When I use a debugger, from what I know it's possible to put a breakpoint, to step, etc... one "statement" at time. If I have (Python, but it's just as example)

```py
   foo = 1
   bar = 2
   baz = 3 * foo + 4 * bar
   qux = 5
```

I can `break` the execution of the code "just before" `baz = 3 * foo + 4 * bar` (when the expression `3 * foo + 4 * bar` has still not been evaluated) or after the assignment, just before the `qux = 5` statement.

Is it possible to instead break "in the half" of the expression? Do I need a specific type of debugger for this, or can it be achieved with most standard tools?

I'm interested both in a "philosophical" and concrete response (specifically for Javascript and Java).

I'm seeing that, with "modern" frameworks, the push is towards a "functional" style. As a matter of facts I see people "scared" of using statements and moving to bigger and complex expressions. And I need to debug those stuff.

Comment: Considering that there are languages that do not have statements, only expressions, and there are debuggers for those languages with support for breakpoints, there must be debuggers which support setting breakpoints in expressions.

Comment: What would you expect to see if you stopped inside an expression, that would be different from stopping before or after a statement?

Comment: If it was C, the language specifically defines that side effects (assignments, increments, function calls made) are observable only between statements (at "sequence points"), and in particular, avoids any standardization of the order of evaluation of operands.  There's also no way to access or name temporary expression state, though maybe drop into machine code to see something.

Comment: Still, fwiw, I prefer short statements, connected by local variables, helpful in debug. So, if you had t1 = 3*foo and t2 = 4*bar, then baz = t1 + t2, you can then see (what was previously) the intermediates using an already existing debugger.  This can also be used as an approach to finding a null pointer or index out of bounds problem in a large expression.

Comment: It's a shame this is getting closed, because I don't think it's really a resource request. Two ways I have set breakpoints inside expressions: debug the assembly code, or split the expression. If it's complex enough that you're worried about intermediate results, it should probably be split anyway, but it doesn't have to be permanent.

Comment: Latest Xcode beta version allows breakpoints “within a line”. Haven’t tried it yet. Might allow breakpoints say before a function call anywhere inside a line.

Comment: @Erik, I think that’s how you often recognise a beginner, who needs to fit as much as possible into one line of code. Over time you learn that splitting it makes it easier to debug, and easier to read.